# Understanding `do` ... `end`

Tags: ruby

I executed the following:

```
def add(x, y)
  return x+y
end

result = add(4, 5) do
  puts "heeeeyyy"
end

result #=> 9
```

I also change `return` to `puts`, but it gives the same result. Please explain to me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: so, you are printing out result. And result is adding 4 and 5 together. that's all you are doing.

Comment: @rapidmode : I trying to understand why the "heeeeyyy" is not printed out. That's why I asked

Comment: @ytbryan : why the  code inside do .. end blocks doesnt exucuted ?

Comment: if you change add() to what @leiliu suggested, it will execute. 

result variable does not have the yield of the block you attached behind.

Therefore, the block you attached with do end is given. But it's not yield until you execute    yield if block_given? as what leilui suggested

Comment: @ytbryan thank you. I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block need to be yield, or it will not be executed

```
def add(x, y)
   yield if block_given?
   return x+y;
end
```

If you want to print the result in your block, then:

```
   def add(x, y)
       yield x+y if block_given?
       return x+y;
    end

   result = add(4, 5) do |result|
     puts result
   end
```

Comment: thank you. Now I understand. I will find some more about YIELD 's stuffs